# Booting up takes longer than it should with a cursor on a black screen

Tags: boot, greeter

`systemd-analyze` outputs the following:

```
Startup finished in 3.917s (firmware) + 2.835s (loader) + 2.592s (kernel) + 2.192s (userspace) = 11.538s 
graphical.target reached after 2.187s in userspace
```

However, I used my phone's stopwatch and getting to the login screen takes about a full minute. I tried press an arrow on the keyboard to see the output, but for most of the booting time there's just a blinking cursor on a black screen (can't type anything). I don't know if the issue is with the booting process or with LightDM.

I'm dual-booting eOS 6 with Windows. The laptop has 8 GB of RAM and an 11th Gen Intel Core i7, so I don't think it should take that long.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: this is the full `systemd-analyze blame` output:

```
825ms snapd.service                                      
502ms apt-daily.service                                  
435ms fwupd-refresh.service                              
389ms lvm2-monitor.service                               
378ms fwupd.service                                      
330ms plymouth-quit-wait.service                         
326ms pantheon-parental-controls.service                 
280ms snapd.seeded.service                               
274ms dev-nvme0n1p7.device                               
266ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-76.mount             
263ms snap-snapd-13640.mount                             
261ms snap-onlyoffice\x2ddesktopeditors-81.mount         
236ms snap-core20-1169.mount                             
235ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-169.mount          
234ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1519.mount            
231ms systemd-logind.service                             
188ms snap-core18-2246.mount                             
171ms dev-loop1.device                                   
166ms dev-loop0.device                                   
133ms snap-bare-5.mount                                  
131ms accounts-daemon.service                            
131ms dev-loop2.device                                   
121ms networkd-dispatcher.service                        
 95ms ua-timer.service                                   
 91ms udisks2.service                                    
 87ms gpu-manager.service                                
 78ms upower.service                                     
 76ms dev-loop3.device                                   
 73ms systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap.service               
 72ms user@1000.service                                  
 67ms user@114.service                                   
 61ms systemd-resolved.service                           
 56ms avahi-daemon.service                               
 55ms bluetooth.service                                  
 54ms NetworkManager.service                             
 52ms polkit.service                                     
 49ms dev-loop4.device                                   
 48ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                       
 44ms systemd-udevd.service                              
 43ms switcheroo-control.service                         
 42ms ModemManager.service                               
 42ms thermald.service                                   
 40ms geoclue.service                                    
 39ms systemd-journal-flush.service                      
 39ms wpa_supplicant.service                             
 36ms systemd-journald.service                           
 35ms keyboard-setup.service                             
 33ms dev-loop5.device                                   
 32ms systemd-timesyncd.service                          
 26ms secureboot-db.service                              
 23ms apparmor.service                                   
 23ms snapd.apparmor.service                             
 22ms plymouth-start.service                             
 22ms dev-mapper-cryptswap.swap                          
 20ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                     
 19ms boot-efi.mount                                     
 17ms systemd-rfkill.service                             
 17ms lightdm.service                                    
 17ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                     
 15ms systemd-modules-load.service                       
 15ms rsyslog.service                                    
 13ms e2scrub_reap.service                               
 12ms alsa-restore.service                               
 12ms systemd-random-seed.service                        
 12ms user-runtime-dir@114.service                       
 12ms colord.service                                     
 11ms plymouth-read-write.service                        
 10ms setvtrgb.service                                   
  9ms grub-common.service                                
  9ms systemd-sysusers.service                           
  9ms pppd-dns.service                                   
  8ms systemd-sysctl.service                             
  7ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                 
  7ms systemd-remount-fs.service                         
  7ms kerneloops.service                                 
  7ms dev-hugepages.mount                                
  6ms dev-mqueue.mount                                   
  6ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                             
  6ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                           
  6ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
  5ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                       
  5ms blk-availability.service                           
  5ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                      
  4ms kmod-static-nodes.service                          
  4ms dev-loop7.device                                   
  4ms systemd-update-utmp.service                        
  3ms dev-loop6.device                                   
  3ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service               
  3ms systemd-user-sessions.service                      
  2ms console-setup.service                              
  2ms atd.service                                        
  1ms ufw.service                                        
  1ms rtkit-daemon.service                               
  1ms openvpn.service                                    
  1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                      
  1ms sys-kernel-config.mount                            
470us snapd.socket
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the full terminal output of `systemd-analyze blame`? This may point to the service that is blocking the system from completing its boot cycle within a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @matigo edited!